# I only get all data one time

Tags: node.js, rest, fs

I'm creating REST API with node.js without express.js framework, and for database I use fs. I'm having problem with get method. All other methods work fine. When I try to get all json files from directory, I can get everything only one time, second and all other times, nothing happens, not even an error, it just stuck for few minutes, and after that I get this error in chrome: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, and this in firefox: TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.". Get one json file works fine. I think problem is in back-end. Because I have same problems with postman.

I'm using node 10.14.1. As I understand when I'm trying to get all files from directory second time, my server.js file don't send any response. And app stops before chosenHandler in server.js line 64.

Get handler:

```
// Resources - get
// Required data: none
// Optional data: ID
handlers._resources.get = (data, callback) => {
// Check that the ID is valid
checkId(data.queryStringObject.id)

if (resourceDBId) {
    // Lookup the resource
    _data.read('resources', resourceDBId, (err, data) => !err &&
    data ? callback(ok, data) : callback(notFound, {Error: 'User doesn\'t exist'}))
} else {
    _data.readAll('resources', (err, data) => {
        if (!err && data) {
            if (data.last) {
                resourcesData.push(data.data)
                callback(ok, resourcesData)
            }
            if (!data.last) resourcesData.push(data.data)
        } else callback(internalServerError, {Error: 'Can\'t get all resources'})
    })
}
```

}

All code are here: https://github.com/FreeDevStan/sale

Comment: Please post the relevant code here: it is not considered good practice to point to external source code in a question/answer, here...

Comment: Its lot of code, so I think it will be much easier to watch it in github

Comment: "and for database I use fs" what do you mean exactly? `fs` is for interacting with filesystem, files are not a database.

Comment: folder is database. .json files are database records/documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readAll method in the lib/data.js file needs to initialize i.
Because i is used undefined, it is treated as global variable i and does not enter the loop, and the callback is not working, so response is not possible.

I recommend you to change it as below.

```
lib.readAll = (dir, callback) => {
fs.readdir(lib.baseDir + dir, (err, data) => {
    if(!err && data) {
        let i = 0;
        while(i < data.length) {
            if (i < data.length - 1) {
                fs.readFile(lib.baseDir + dir + '/' + data[i], 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
                    let parsedContent = helpers.parseJsonToObject(content)
                    err ? callback(err, content) : callback(false, {last: false, data: parsedContent})
                })
            } if (i === data.length - 1) {
                fs.readFile(lib.baseDir + dir + '/' + data[i], 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
                    let parsedContent = helpers.parseJsonToObject(content)
                    err ? callback(err, content) : callback(false, {last: true, data: parsedContent})
                })
            }
            i++
        }
    } else callback(err, data)
})
```

}

Comment: It almost helped, but in this case. when i try to get all, at first I get 2 files, second time I get 4 files, third time 6 files and so on. But in database there are only 2 files

Comment: I found the answer. Problem was in handlers.js, I had to initialize resourcesData in _data.readAll callback, not in files top

Comment: Thanks for help ;)

Comment: However, this is only for the current problem resolution, and I think it is good to have the callback called even when the data is if(0 == i) to work in the absence of the data.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by your comment. And now I have a another problem :D Sometimes I get only second file data, sometimes both files data.